# how can I use FB comments plugin in one page with different users

Tags: facebook, plugins

I have a profile page that displays users profile by sending different Id param to it. I added FB comment plugin to it, but the comments show with all users I cannot display the plugin with each user separately.

Answer (score 1):

you need a unique url for every profile 
use this code  if you want to use HTML 5 & your programing lang is php

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/?unique=<?php echo $user_id ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

visit here for more infos

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/